# VMWare Fusion - Where does a shared folder appear if the Virtual OS is “Snow Leopard Server”?

Tags: snow-leopard, sharing, folders, vmware, virtualization

I have a Mac running VMWare Fusion with "Snow Leopard Server" running as the guest, virtual OS.

It says that I can specify a shared folder to shared between the main Mac OS and the virtual Snow Leopard Server OS.

I've specified a shared folder, however, this folder is not showing up anywhere on the virtual server. Maybe I just have no idea where it should show up, so perhaps I'm not looking in the right place.

Does anyone know where I would find the shared folder within Snow Leopard Server running virtually in VMWare Fusion?

Answer (score 4):

[I received a correct answer on VMWare community forum](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/462684):

> Using VMware Shared Folders requires VMware Tools be installed in the Guest OS, have you installed VMware Tools?
>
> If yes make sure you have Shared Folders turned on in the Virtual Machine Settings and have added a shared folder.
>
> If that has been done there should be a `VMware Shared Folders` alias on the Guest OSes Desktop.
>
> Also look in `/Volumes` for a directory named `VMware Shared Folders` as that is the mount point in OS X for VMware Shared Folders.

Comment: We like to include the details of the answer, not just the link, to avoid link rot. As such, I've edited your answer to include the relevant details and kept the attribution link.